# Why does it omit "ed" when read it as in "flopped down"?

Tags: spoken-english

> Her loose hair flopped down in front of her face and she casually
>   flicked it aside

[sound source](https://forvo.com/phrase/her_loose_hair_flopped_down_in_front_of_her_face_and_she_casually_flicked_it_aside/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He *certainly* says *'..ed'* But since the word is followed by 'd' again, it is not clearly heard especially when we are non-native speakers.

We need to practice a lot to understand native speakers' pronunciation. This one is one of those examples where we miss the word!

Comment: I think this is the right answer, I can't think of a reason one would intentionally omit that ed, but it's easy to trip over the ...ed d... combination so a native speaker probably subconsciously adjusts the emphasis to compensate

Comment: I agree - to this US English speaker, he says "...ed", but then again, I know that's what he's supposed to be saying, so it's easy for me to think that's what he says!  In practice, it's really hard to hear the difference if you don't know it's there.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because 'ed' follows a voiceless 'p' sound, in which case 'ed' is replaced by 't' sound.

Comment: That's true, but it doesn't explain why the /t/ would be omitted.  Have you considered what else might be a factor, for example the following /d/ of *down*?